# Installing ubuntu server on USB - confused about disk partitioning - need help

Tags: 14.04, server, live-usb

I am a Linux newbie with a computer with Windows 7, an 80-GB SSD "C" drive with my OS and program files on it, and a 1-TB "D" drive with my Windows 7 data. I am trying to install "ubuntu-14.04.3-server-amd64.iso" onto a 32-GB USB-3 flash drive. When I get done, I want a bootable ubuntu server USB drive on which I can install some additional Linux software. I am using the PenDrive software. I get so far each time, then break into a cold sweat that I am going to destroy my Windows 7 install, so I abort. The following images tell the story, and where I need help. The first image shows one of the questions I answered during the ubuntu server install. I said "No", but am not sure if it is the right answer. I don't want to "unmount" my Windows 7 installation :).

- [Saying "No" to unmounting /dev/sda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ET4Z.jpg)

It refers to /dev/sda. I was "guessing" that this referred to my "C" drive where Windows 7 was installed, so I said "No", don't unmount anything. I guess saying "No" was ok. It occurred to me that /dev/sda could be referring to the flash drive in which case I don't know what to do. In any case, I said "No" and kept going. Then I came to the following screen, which is where I get totally freaked out. I don't understand what it is asking, I am not sure what /dev/sda means for sure, and I don't know what /dev/sdc means. Is it my "C" or "D" drive, with my precious data on it. There are so many options, and each of them scares me to death. So I just abort the whole process. I have been through this three times already, and this screen stops me cold. The fact that the first line is highlighted in red only reflects that is where the screen defaults to when it appears. I don't know what to do. Help!

- [Many options, several of which seem to dynamite my Windows 7 install!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9lJO.jpg)

I sort of detect that with a "desktop" install, it might be more automatic. But I want a "server" install, which seems to be more complicated. Go figure :).

Comment: Why not just disconnect the HDD with Windows before the installation (may be even pull it out, and put it in a closet)? That way, no matter what, you'll know it's safe. ...don't know what that is: "I am using the PenDrive software". How is it related to the question?

Comment: With multiple drives, you do not want any auto install option. Are you attempting to install to the same flash drive that you are installing from? Drives in Linux are sda, sdb, sdc etc And partitions are numbers with the drive like sda1, sda2, sdb1. In Windows a D: drive can be a partition on first drive like sda2 or on second drive as sdb1 for example. Best to understand partitions in Linux. It may be better to start with a desktop install. You can add all the server programs. System is the same, just software included. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace.

Comment: Hi mikewhatever, good questions. I am using an HP Envy 17 laptop with fixed drives, so can't remove one. If it was a desktop, great idea. I mention the PenDrive software, because that is the platform with which I am trying to create a bootable flash drive. There are several and they all appear to work differently.